# A regular expressions in Java/Android

Tags: java, android, regex

I've been here in a battle because of regular expressions ..

I'm getting something like that [5.00,10.00,20.00] and I want to get just the numbers that is, 5.00, 10.00 and 20.00. And do not get tou get a regex that I do this separation

In this case I'm only getting 3 numbers, but can I get more than three.

Someone can help me in the regular expression to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one suggestion:

```
String input = "[5.00,10.00,20.00]";

String[] parts = input.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "").split(",");
```

You could also strip out `[` and `]` using `String.substring` without regular expressions.

```
String[] parts = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1).split(",");
```

---

Note that `split` doesn't handle the empty string very well in this situation. If you may get `"[]"` as input, I suggest you do something like

```
input = input.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
String[] parts = input.isEmpty() ? new String[] {} : input.split(",");
```

Comment: Thank but the parameters substring  are integer values ​​and does not accept the characters [and]

Answer (score 3):

Why use a regexp? A Scanner might be much more suitable:

```
String input = "[5.00,10.00,20.00]";
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(input.trim()).useDelimiter(";|\\]").skip("\\[");
while (scanner.hasNextDouble()){
  System.out.println(scanner.nextDouble());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think aioobe's answer might be better for what you are doing, but if you absolutely want a regex here is one:

```
String input = "[5.00,10.00,20.00]";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?:([\\d\\.]+)[,]?)");
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(input);
While(match.find()) {
    new Double(match.group(1));//you can add this to a collection or something
}
```